# WINMERGE Shows Chinese Characters but its just XML

Tags: xml, merge, document, winmerge

I want to merge two XML documents with WinMerge but the file content is displayed as Chinese characters.

Here my XML (Edited with VS Code):
File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Object>
    <TestProperty>Test2</TestProperty>
</Object>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Object>
    <TestProperty>Test</TestProperty>
</Object>
```

I´ve tried to change CodePage to UTF-8 and to Unicode but nothing changed.
Here a Picture of WinMerge:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Edit > Options
2. Codepage
3. Select `System codepage`
4. Un-select `Detect codepage info for these types of files: .html, .rc, .xml`
5. OK
6. Restart WinMerge

For more details: See "18.2. Detect codepage info for these files: .html, .rc, .xml" in https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Configuration.html